# Debian: how to restart iwlwifi drivers when they fail to load

Tags: drivers, debian, wifi-driver, iwlwifi

I'm using Debian 12, `firmware-iwlwifi` installed and usually works just fine but sometimes when I boot the pc the wifi adapter is not ready and the only thing that work is reboot the whole machine.

I've tryed with modprobe, as I read around the web:

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi && sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

But doesnt work, and in my `dmesg` i get those:

```
  256.865480] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
[  257.129411] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: CSR_RESET = 0x10
[  257.129415] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Host monitor block 0x0 vector 0x0
[  257.129514] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 0]: 0x3f1d0430
[  257.129516] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 1]: 0x3f1d0430
[  257.129518] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 2]: 0x3f1d0430
[  257.129520] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 3]: 0x3f1d0030
[  257.129522] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 4]: 0x3f1d0030
[  257.129524] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 5]: 0x3f1d0030
[  257.129525] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 6]: 0x3f1d0030
[  257.129527] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 7]: 0x3f1d0030
[  257.129529] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 8]: 0x3f1d0030
[  257.129531] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 9]: 0x3f1d0030
[  257.129533] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 10]: 0x3f1d0030
[  257.129535] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 11]: 0x3f1d0030
[  257.129536] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 12]: 0x3f1d0430
[  257.129538] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 13]: 0x3f1d0430
[  257.129540] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 14]: 0x3f1d0430
[  257.129541] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Host monitor block 0x0 vector 0x1
[  257.129543] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 0]: 0x040066c2
[  257.129545] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 1]: 0x040066c2
[  257.129547] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 2]: 0x040066c2
[  257.129549] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 3]: 0x040066c2
[  257.129550] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 4]: 0x040066c2
[  257.129552] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 5]: 0x040066c2
[  257.129554] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 6]: 0x040066c2
[  257.129556] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 7]: 0x040066c2
[  257.129558] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 8]: 0x040066c2
[  257.129560] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 9]: 0x040066c2
[  257.129561] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 10]: 0x040066c2
[  257.129563] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 11]: 0x040066c2
[  257.129565] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 12]: 0x040066c2
[  257.129567] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 13]: 0x040066c2
[  257.129569] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 14]: 0x040066c2
[  257.129570] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Host monitor block 0x0 vector 0x6
[  257.129572] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 0]: 0xb00c7c75
[  257.129574] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 1]: 0xb00c7c75
[  257.129576] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 2]: 0xb00c7c75
[  257.129577] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 3]: 0xb00c7c75
[  257.129579] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 4]: 0xb00c7c75
[  257.129581] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 5]: 0xe00c7c75
[  257.129583] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 6]: 0xe00c7c75
[  257.129585] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 7]: 0xe00c7c75
[  257.129587] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 8]: 0xe00c7c75
[  257.129589] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 9]: 0xe00c7c75
[  257.129590] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 10]: 0xe00c7c75
[  257.129592] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 11]: 0xe00c7c75
[  257.129594] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 12]: 0xe00c7c75
[  257.129596] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 13]: 0xa00c7c75
[  257.129598] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 14]: 0xb00c7c75
[  257.129599] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Host monitor block 0x22 vector 0x0
[  257.129601] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 0]: 0x59cec019
[  257.129620] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:00:14.3 failed with error -110
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dont know if a tech solution, but I solved doing this:

- Enable airplane mode
- disabling the driver via modprobe -r
- Disable airplane mode
- Re-enable the driver via modprobe
- Restart NetworkManager and networking service (via systemctl)